# IE webdriver instances

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir, watir-webdriver

Is there any way I could control the number of IE instances that can be instantiated by a webdriver, maybe by setting max instances or something? I am using `watir-webdriver` with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using a selenium grid. While registering the RC to hub you can specify the maxSession and maxInstances.

> Configuring the nodes
>
> The node can be configured in 2 different ways; one is by specifying
>   command line parameters, the other is by specifying a json file.
>   Configuring the nodes by command line
>
> By default, this starts 11 browsers : 5 Firefox, 5 Chrome, 1 Internet
>   Explorer. The maximum number of concurrent tests is set to 5 by
>   default. To change this and other browser settings, you can pass in
>   parameters to each -browser switch (each switch represents a node
>   based on your parameters). If you use the -browser parameter, the
>   default browsers will be ignored and only what you specify command
>   line will be used.
>
> -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,maxInstances=5,platform=LINUX
>
> This setting starts 5 Firefox 3.6 nodes on a linux machine.
>
> If your remote machine has multiple versions of Firefox you’d like to
>   use, you can map the location of each binary to a particular version
>   on the same machine:
>
> -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,firefox_binary=/home/myhomedir/firefox36/firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=LINUX
>   -browser browserName=firefox,version=4,firefox_binary=/home/myhomedir/firefox4/firefox,maxInstances=4,platform=LINUX
>
> Tip: If you need to provide a space somewhere in your browser
>   parameters, then surround the parameters with quotation marks:
>
> -browser “browserName=firefox,version=3.6,firefox_binary=c:\Program Files\firefox ,maxInstances=3, platform=WINDOWS”

Link to Selenium Wiki - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2